# Only allow a specific Value Format in a Textbox C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, string-formatting

I want to make sure that the Input of my Textbox is of a specific Format.

`+101.800`
`-085.000`
`+655.873`

The correct length aswell as the +/- Symbol is important for communication in the process.

I thought about using a `MaskedTextbox` but that wouldn't force the user to add the +/-Symbols if I understand the documentation correctly.

Comment: So if I understand correctly by your examples, you want to only accept numbers with three digits before the decimal point and three decimals of positive or negative values? Please be specific.

Comment: Yes you understand it correctly three digits befor the decimal Point and three after. And infront i need the + or - Symbol aswell.

Comment: Try following mask `#000.000`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write in Leave event for check value after leaving textbox and make text color red if that is wrong value for user's attention and disable submit button for preventing to press button before write the number in correct format.

```
private void myInput_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Regex r = new Regex(@"^[+-]?[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}$");
    Match m = r.Match(InputTextbox.Text);
    if (!m.Success)
    {
         myInput.ForeColor =  Color.Red;  // Text color will go red
         submitBtn.Enabled = false;  // Submit button is disabled now
    }
    else
    {
         myInput.ForeColor =  Color.Black;
         submitBtn.Enabled = true; // Submit button is enabled now
    }
}
```

Comment: ty for your help

Comment: @Shining @ symbol added to regex. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this Regex:

```
private void InputTextbox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Regex r = new Regex(@"^[+-]?[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}$");
    Match m = r.Match(InputTextbox.Text);
    if (m.Success)
    {
        // Code
    }
}
```

Comment: You should write this in Leave event or something more related, when text is changing user is typing yet and we can't check that text.

Comment: Ty for your quick answer

Answer (score 0):

I used the Regex of @Max Voisard but it gave me an error of unknown Escape Sequnece so i added the @Symbol which made it work for me.

```
private void textBox18_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            Regex r = new Regex(@"^[+-]?[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}$");

            Match m = r.Match(((TextBox)sender).Text);
            if (!m.Success)

            {
                // Cancel the event and select the text to be corrected by the user.
                e.Cancel = true;
                ((TextBox)sender).Select(0, ((TextBox)sender).Text.Length);



            }
        }
```